# How to float:left text, next to a Afflux Gallary using Gmedia

Tags: css, wordpress, css-float

I am using a wordpress plugin called Gmedia Gallaries and would like to float the text that I have below it so that it appears next to the gallary on the right hand side.

I have tried the following:

```
.afflux_module {
overflow: hidden;
float:none;
margin-right: 20px;
}
.nextToPic{
float:none;
padding: 15px;
clear:both;
}
```

but it does not seem to work, any help?

this is the site I am workig on - http://thestudentbubble.com/hidden-gems/hidden-gems-restaurants/afriteo/

Comment: it seems the text IS on the right of the gallery..

Comment: interesting, but how can i make it apear next tothe gallery on the right hand side,where the white space is? urrently it is at the bottom.

Comment: you are talking about the text inside of .bioText that start's with "Set up by a recent Exeter Uni graduate,....." right?

Comment: yes I am as well as the contact details.

Comment: well I'm looking at the page in chrome and it seems fine to me.. what browser you're looking with, can you make a screenshot?

Comment: What does look weird is that there's a white gap above the gallery pic... i see the gallery is also flash, which I wouldn't recommend, you can do the same gallery with html/css/js and have it working faster, and easier to manage

Comment: Iam using Firefox. The Gap is probably a bit too much padding. Sorry can't upload pictures because I have not got enough reputations. 

How would I be able to create the same using JS? I have never used JS before.

Comment: Internet explorer has the same issue.

Comment: Ok. now I see your issue.. if you want the text to be on the right just give .afflux_module { float:left;}.. you can give it a width also so the text has more room.. regarding JS that would be a tutorial, just google it.

Comment: If i do float:left then the gallery dissapears as you can see now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put the text beside the gallery, add this to your CSS file:

```
.afflux_module {
    float: left;
}
```